# SwiftUI: Difference between async{} and Task.init{ }

Tags: swiftui, async-await

I am using Xcode 13.4 and trying to launch an async function when the Picker changes.

```
Picker(NSLocalizedString("Please choose a project", comment: ""), selection: $selectedProjectKey) {
    ForEach(projectKeys, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
    }
}
.font(.system(size: 14))
.onChange(of: selectedProjectKey, perform: { (selectedKey) in
    print("selected key \(selectedKey)")
    async {
        do {
            let projectTasks = try await api.getProjectTasksByProjectKey(projectKey: selectedKey)
            projectTasksKeys = projectTasks.map{$0.key}
        } catch {
            /// To define error behavour
        }
        
    }
})
```

It works, but I know that async is deprecated (yellow warning).
That's why, I tried with `Task.init {... }` or `Task { ... }` and instead, I get an error:

> "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Decoder' that does not
> accept a closure".

I suppose that I did something definitely wrong but I can't understand what it is and what difference there is between `async{...}` and `Task.init { ... }` .

Comment: There is a chance you have already defined Task as a `struct Task: Codable` somewhere

Answer (score 1):

it's been a while but for anyone else looking, make sure you're using the right import.

Command-click to have it take you to the source. I realized I was using a `Task` class associated with `FHIR` from `HealthSoftware`.

To fix it, I used `SwiftUI.Task` before the closure.

Comment: You just saved my bacon here... It's even more wild if you have a custom model `Task` and wonder why wrapping an async call in `Task{}` in a Button all of a sudden is not working in this specific project... 